# Different WordPress front page for logged out and logged in users, excluding admin

Tags: wordpress

I've managed, with the help of the great content available on stackoverflow, to forward logged in users to a different page on my wordpress powered site. I would however like to exclude the admin role from this. Is this possible?

```
<?php if(is_front_page()) { if (is_user_logged_in()) { $newURL = 'https://myurl.com/forwardloggedin';; header('Location: '.$newURL); } } ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What code do you have that is working and redirecting your users? Also what have you tried so far or researched? [Its hard to help with the small description you have provided so far.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks and apologies - missed the proper formatting to add code - amended my initial post.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [current_user_can](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) function. Also, WordPress already has redirect functions: [wp_safe_redirect](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_safe_redirect) and [wp_redirect](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/) so you don't have to use the PHP's header('Location')

Check the code below:

```
if ( is_front_page() ) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
        $new_url = 'https://myurl.com/forwardloggedin';
        wp_safe_redirect( $new_url );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks so much! Do I need to add this to my theme functions?

Comment: Yes and you have to wrap it in a function and call it on init action https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init